# Parse: code 111 - can't add a non-pointer to a relation

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, entity-relationship

I have a bunch of entries in a list view that are created by users. I want users to be able to flag them for review so I set up a 'flaggedBy' relationship like so:

```
var relation = entry.relation('flaggedBy');
relation.add(Parse.User.current());
entry.save(null,{
    success:function(flag){
        alert('Entry flagged for review');
    }
});
```

However, when I try to save, I get the error:

```
code 111 - can't add a non-pointer to a relation
```

All the other answers for this problem say I'm trying to add a relationship to an object that hasn't been saved yet but I do have a user account. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Parse.User.current() was null because I was working locally and I was using Facebook as my login mechanism (I haven't set up a local way to do this).